# My Sister's Six Children

Tags: calculation-puzzle

My sister has six children whose ages add up to 40. The ages of any two of her three boys have a common divisor greater than 1, and so do the ages of any two of the ages of her three girls. However, only one of the boy's ages has a common divisor with the age of one of the girls.

How old are my sister's six children?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are

> $3$, $3$, $6$, $7$, $7$, and $14$.